# Edit-triggered timestamp doesn't trigger fast enough

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, triggers, timestamp

I have a Google Sheet that has 15 people working on it. I am using the below script to add a timestamp to column X, whenever data is entered into column Q:

```
var COLUMNTOCHECK = 17;
var DATETIMELOCATION = [0, 6];
var SHEETNAME = 'Requires Review'

function onEdit(e) {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  if (sheet.getSheetName() == SHEETNAME) { 
    var selectedCell = ss.getActiveCell();
    if (selectedCell.getColumn() == COLUMNTOCHECK) { 
      var dateTimeCell = selectedCell.offset(DATETIMELOCATION[0], DATETIMELOCATION[1]);
      dateTimeCell.setValue(new Date(new Date().setHours(0, 0, 0, 0)))
                  .setNumberFormat('MM/d/yy');
    }
  }
}
```

The script works, just not all the time. I imagine this is because there are instances where several users are making edits in column Q simultaneously, and the script can't keep up. Is there a way to fix this? Is there a way to make another script that does the same as the above, but instead of an edit trigger, it runs every minute or so and adds the timestamp en masse to all cells in column Q that are filled?

Comment: Yes, you can use a time-based trigger script to achieve similar effects.  Review Apps Script "best practices" for some starter tips on batch methods. You may have better luck in your `onEdit` if you actually use the [event object `e`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#edit) instead of `Active____`

Answer (score 0):

try this code, it will go a bit faster as you will use the event object `e` that already contains the active range in it:

```
var COLUMNTOCHECK = 17;
var DATETIMELOCATION = [0, 6];
var SHEETNAME = 'Requires Review'

function onEdit(e) {
  if (e.range.getSheet().getName() == SHEETNAME) { 
    if (e.range.getColumn() == COLUMNTOCHECK) { 
      var dateTimeCell = e.range.offset(DATETIMELOCATION[0], DATETIMELOCATION[1]);
      dateTimeCell.setValue(new Date(new Date().setHours(0, 0, 0, 0)))
                  .setNumberFormat('MM/d/yy');
    }
  }
}
```

or use a time trigger to activate your function every x minutes/hours. In this example you just have to execute `createTrigger`once.

```
var COLUMNTOCHECK = 17;
var DATETIMELOCATION = [0, 6];
var SHEETNAME = 'Requires Review'

function createTrigger()
{
  ScriptApp.newTrigger("myFunction")
    .timeBased()
    //triggers every 2 hours
      .everyHours(2)
        .create();
}

function myFunction() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName(SHEETNAME);
  //then grab the correct range and set Values
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: when using the onEdit you provided, I get the following error:
TypeError: Cannot read property "range" from undefined. (line 7, file "Code")

Comment: @Jesse really weird can you share the spreadsheet link please?